# Blank output in javascript

Tags: javascript

Helo friends i have coded a js script to find out the value of this in a function.The code is

```
function hello(this) {
this.value = 10;
document.write(this);
};


var c = new hello(c);
c();
```

But i get this output as blank...I know this depends upon how the function is called and here c is the value of this..So the output must be c.

Do i wanna change `new hello(to any string)` here or just c like i did.

Please help me to solve this and make me correct...Any help would be appreciated ..Thanks..

Comment: [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging). Seriously, being able to debug code on your own is as important as knowing the language itself. When I run your code, I get the error `SyntaxError: missing formal parameter`. Hint: You can't declare a variable or parameter with name `this` and `c` is not a function. I also don't think `c` works as you expect it to work.

Comment: Don't use `this` as a parameter. Use a better name. `this` means something: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this . Also, why are you passing `c` into the constructor, which is the variable?

Comment: so instead of calling with c we can call the function like hello('anyvalue'); ..right ?

Comment: All the above.  Not to mention you really shouldn't be using `document.write`.  We've had better ways since 1997, at least.

Comment: Yep, you can call any function with any value you want. Whether it makes sense is a different question. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions to learn how functions work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you can not use "this" as a variable in javascript because it is a reserved keyword you better use something else. Secondly, if you want to pass a string to a function you must enclose it between either single (') quotes or double quotes ("). Thirdly, your function does not return any value, so there is no need really to assign it to a variable. Forthly, you are assigning 10 to a property in "ths" object but you are returning ths not ths.value if you know what i mean. That was my comment. The correction for your code will be:

```
function hello(ths) {
document.write(ths);
};

hello("your string goes here");
```

Comment: that has been said. displaying something on the browser using document.write function is not really practical. I would recommend you  learn JQuery which handles that task in a much easier way than DOM, which was the old way.

Comment: You can always edit your answer and add it there instead of adding as a comment..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
/* incoming variable we set when calling our function, currently reads: Hello there! */
var hello = function(incoming) { 
     /* incoming variable being overwritten, now reads: 10 */
     incoming = 10; 
     /* writing 10 to document, overwriting anything already written to document */
     document.write(this); 
};
/* calling your function 'hello' as well as setting incoming variable to: Hello there! */
var a = new hello('Hello there!');
```

Answer (score 0):

Framework structure, solid. I assume you're after something like this?

```
function hello ()
{
    // inside a function (soon to be object) "this" refers to that object
    this.value = 10; // can and must be called by c.value outside of the declared function

    this.sayHello = function( msg )
    {
        this.value = msg; // is equal to c.value (outside of hello), overwrites old value with new message
        document.write( msg );
    }
}

// 'new' prefix types an object, represented by 'c'
var c = new hello;

c.sayHello( 'your message' );
// Your most recent message is stored in c.value
```